# UTF text in SDL2

Tags: c++, utf-8, sdl-2

I just finished creating a function to cache any loaded font in the small game engine I'm building in SDL2, the following function works flawlessly and rendering text is about 12 times faster than creating a new SDL_Surface each time I need text. However, as you can see, it caches only ANSI characters, this is fine for English, but not if I ever want to translate my game (German umlauts, or Cyrillic glyphs are not available in ANSI)

```
void cacheFonts(){
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < GlobalFontAssets.size; i++){
        SDL_Colour color_font = {255, 255, 255, 255};
        std::vector<SDL_Texture*> tempVector;
        for(int j = 32; j < 128; j++){
            char temp[2];
            temp[0] = j;
            temp[1] = 0;
            SDL_Surface* glyph = TTF_RenderUTF8_Blended(GlobalFontAssets.fonts[i], temp, color_font);  
            SDL_Texture* texture = 
            SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, glyph);
            tempVector.push_back(texture);  
            SDL_FreeSurface(glyph);
        }
        GlobalFontAssets.cache.push_back(tempVector);
    }
    printf("Global Fonts Cached!\n");
}
```

I have tried using `wchar_t`, and looping from 0 to 256^2, however I can not get any characters to print even using `printf`, `wprintf`, `cout` and `wcout`, However if I do:

```
std::string str = "Привет, öäü"
printf("%s\n", str.c_str());
```

Then it prints the string on the terminal just fine. I should mention that  I am on Ubuntu 16.04, so a Windows only solution doesn't work for me, ideally I wish to do this in a portable manner. To those not familiar with SDL, all I need is a way to get every UTF8 Character in a C string. I hope that this is possible.

Comment: Hmmm, C-ish C++ code.  Suggest only 1 language tag to improve the post.

Comment: There are *millions* of Unicode glyphs, as compared to 256 extended ASCII characters.  You can't just blindly use the same approach.  Among other things, in Unicode there are "combining characters", which can't be rendered separately from the characters the modify, you have to work on units of glyphs, not characters.

Comment: @BenVoigt You mean Latin-1 instead of ASCII?

Comment: @Deduplicator: I meant "extended ASCII".  For any 8-bit character set, there are 256 possible values.

Comment: In addition, the naive layout algorithm (texture each glyph, add the width of character cell to X coordinate, texture the next one) doesn't work when multilingual support is required.  Some languages layout from right-to-left.  Some are even weirder.

Comment: I just read that the first 2000 UTF-8 Chars are enough for every European language. And I would reconsider my approach, but I can't do that until I can at least print these Chars to the terminal.

Comment: @Max that's possible but SDL_ttf expects UTF8 (as the function name suggests). Unicode and UTF8 are not the same, you need to convert your numeric sequence to UTF8 - e.g. with `u8_wc_toutf8` from http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/unicode.html . It might also be better to use uint32_t instead of wchar_t  as the latter is only 2 bytes on some platforms (e.g. windows).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Addressing only this portion of the question:

> all I need is a way to get every UTF8 Character in a C string

[Wikipedia has a nice table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) showing the various encoding rules, the range of codepoints that each covers, and the corresponding UTF-8 length and data bytes.

For covering [the first 2000-odd characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45716356/utf-text-in-sdl2/45738733#comment78391254_45716356), just generate all the one- and two-byte patterns:

```
char s[3] = { 0 };
for(s[0] = 0x00; s[0] < 0x80u; ++s[0]) { // can start at 0x20 to skip control characters
    // one byte encodings
}
for(s[0] = 0xC0u; s[0] < 0xE0u; ++s[0]) {
   for(s[1] = 0x80u; s[1] < 0xC0u; ++s[1]) {
      // two byte encodings
   }
}
```

It's no coincidence that the values `0x80u` and `0xC0u` appear more than once in the loop conditions -- the fact that there is no overlap between lead bytes and following bytes is what gives UTF-8 its self-synchronizing property.

I guess you're relying on the following fact (quoted from Wikipedia):

> The first 128 characters (US-ASCII) need one byte. The next 1,920 characters need two bytes to encode, which covers the remainder of almost all Latin-script alphabets, and also Greek, Cyrillic, Coptic, Armenian, Hebrew, Arabic, Syriac, Thaana and N'Ko alphabets, as well as Combining Diacritical Marks.

Because this range contains combining marks, you will have quite a few entries that can't be rendered alone.  Whether you skip them or just handle the resulting confusion from the text layout engine is up to you.

Comment: This does indeed do what I asked, Thank you. I have, however, decided to change my approach. I now only cache ASCII chars in this manner as that doesn't take much vram at all and is very fast to draw. For non ASCII text, I have created a LRU cache using a `std::list` and `std::unordered_map` which holds the last 100 string draws. Which when text doesn't change extremely fast is just as fast as the previous method, once the cache is created of course. I now only check if a string uses any non standard chars and use the appropriate function. It was indeed crazy to think I can cache all of UTF8.